# If $X$ is compact then prove that $C(X)=C_0(X)=C_c(X)$

Tags: functional-analysis

> If $X$ is compact then prove that
>   $C(X)=C_0(X)=C_c(X)$.

My effort: We know that for any $X$, $C(x)\supseteq C_0(X)\supseteq C_c(X)$. Now to prove the reverse let $f\in C(X)$, Then $f$ is continuous bounded on the compact set $X$.We have to show that for any $\epsilon\ge0$ there is a closed compact set $K$ such that$|f(x)|<\epsilon$ for $x\notin K$. But I dont understand how to do this. Please help.

Comment: Can you think of one compact set that works for all $\epsilon > 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Use $K=X$. Then think what $K^c$ is.

Comment: let $\lambda =max_{x\in X} f(x)$,then $f(x)\le \lambda$ for all $x \notin \phi$. Is this the argument?

Comment: No, let $\epsilon>$. Then $f(x)\leq \epsilon$ for all $x\in\emptyset$ as these statements about the empty sets are true.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$X$ is compact and statements about the empty set are vacuously true.